# Modal with image slider - get name and numbering

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I created a modal that contains an image slider, using the bootstrap ngb-carousel.

Is there a way to display the name of the current slider image in the modal header and the image numbering in the modal footer?

That is, if one of the slider's images is in the image, in the modal header I intend to present your name and in the footer I intend to present the current numbering, that is, as I have 3 images and I am in the 1st, in the footer I must have 1/3. When changing the image of the slider the names and numbering change.

Can anyone help me? I couldn't implement any event that would allow me to get this :(

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbyb34?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Code**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Show images Modal
</button>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Name Image !</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ngb-carousel id="carousel" #carouse *ngIf="data" (slide)="change($event)">
                    <ng-template *ngFor="let imgIdx of data; let i = index" [id]="i" ngbSlide>
                        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                            <img [src]="imgIdx.image" [alt]="">
                          </div>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>{{imgIdx.head}}</h3>
                                <p>{{imgIdx.data}}</p>
                            </div>
                    </ng-template>
                </ngb-carousel>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                Number images (1/3)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just declare three variables: (*)

```
  //it's necesary, at first give manually the initial value

  imgName:string=this.data[0].name
  imgNumber:number=1
  imgLength:number=this.data.length
```

in change function change this variables:

```
  change(data){
    this.imgNumber=data.current+1;
    this.imgName=this.data[data.current].name
  }
```

Your .html use this variables:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
            ...
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{imgName}}!</h4>
            ....
        <div class="modal-footer">
            Number images ({{imgNumber}}/{{imgLength}})
        </div>
        ...
</div>
```

[your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqqjeu?file=src/app/app.component.html)

(*)If you want know more about display data and interpolation see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#displaying-data-in-views)

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you !